# Cycle Property over Matroids

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matroids

The [cycle property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Cycle_property) on graphs states, that

> For any cycle $C$ in a graph, if the weight of an edge $e$ of $C$ is
>   larger than the individual weights of all other edges of $C$, then this
>   edge cannot belong to a minimum spanning tree.

Now I'm interested in generalizing this statement to matroids, but I cannot find a way of proving or disproving it.

Does the following hold?

> For any cycle $C$ in a matroid, if the weight of an element $e\in C$ is larger
>   than the individual weights of all other elements in $C$, then $e$ cannot
>   belong to a minimal basis of the matroid.

Comment: A search for matroids and the greedy algorithm should prove enlightening.

Comment: I am familiar with the greedy algorithm, and that it won't find a solution containing any $e$ as in my question.

What I'm concerned with is, wouldn't it possible that there exists a minimal basis that greedy cannot find?

Comment: If an algorithm doesn't work, then it's not much of an algorithm.

Comment: @Konrad If there is a non-unique minimal basis, then the greedy algorithm must make choices about which elements of the ground set of a matroid to delete or add. For any minimal basis, there is a sequence of choices which lead to it (i.e. if we are adding elements of minimal weight which keep our set independent, add the element in your minimal basis).